# Why @Transient can't be used with val fields?

Tags: kotlin

I wrote data class

```
data class FileHeader(
    val relativePath: String,
    val orderNumber: Long,
    val bodySize: Int
) : Serializable {
@Transient
var headerSize: Int = 0
    get() = relativePath.length + 8
}
```

It works as i expect.

But why i can't use @Transient with val field?

The error is:

This annotation is not applicable to target member property without backing field or delegate

Are there any reasons why it implemented in this way?

Comment: Which version of Kotlin are you using? I tried this with 1.3.21 and it seems to work.

Comment: @AlexanderEgger I get the error on http://try.kotlinlang.org/, as expected. Maybe you didn't change `var` to `val`?

Comment: Version is 1.3.20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation

> [Marks the JVM backing field of the annotated property as `transient`, meaning that it is not part of the default serialized form of the object.](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-transient/index.html)

The default serialization works on fields and doesn't care about getter methods. So if there's no backing field, there's nothing to serialize (and nothing to mark as `transient` in bytecode). The annotation would be useless in this case, so the designers chose to make it an error.

If you don't see why there's no backing field:

> [A backing field will be generated for a property if it uses the default implementation of at least one of the accessors, or if a custom accessor references it through the field identifier.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

With your `var`, the backing field is needed by the default setter; when you change it to `val`, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@get:javax.persistence.Transient
val headerSize
  get() { ... }
```